# ¿Cómo funciona error_reporting?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los errores generados en PHP o filtrarlos para que solo se muestren los de cierto nivel?

`echo ERROR ??`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### error_reporting

```
int error_reporting ([ int $level ] )
```

La función `error_reporting()` establece la directiva [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) en tiempo de ejecución. PHP tiene varios niveles de errores para notificar, al utilizar ésta función se define el nivel de duración (tiempo de ejecución) de sus scripts. Si el parámetro opcional level no se define, la función `error_reporting()` sólo devolverá el nivel actual de notificación de error.

**Parámetros**

*level*

El nuevo nivel de [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). Este nivel toma una máscara de bit o constantes nominadas. Al utilizar constantes nominadas se recomienda encarecidamente asegurar la compatibilidad para versiones futuras. Según se añaden niveles de error, el rango de los enteros incrementa, por lo que los niveles antiguos de errores basados en enteros no siempre se comportarán como se esperaba.

Las constantes de niveles de error disponibles, y los significados actuales de esos niveles de error están descritos en [constantes predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.constants.php).

**Valores devueltos**

Devuelve el nivel antiguo de [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) o el nivel actual si el parámetro level no se proporciona.

**Ejemplo**

```
<?php

// Desactivar toda notificación de error
error_reporting(0);

// Notificar solamente errores de ejecución
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Notificar E_NOTICE también puede ser bueno (para informar de variables
// no inicializadas o capturar errores en nombres de variables ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Notificar todos los errores excepto E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Notificar todos los errores de PHP (ver el registro de cambios)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Notificar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(-1);

// Lo mismo que error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```