# ERROR 500 al crear objeto en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Cuando creo un objeto a través del inspector de elementos en la pestaña de red me sale error 500 y no muestra nada por pantalla. El codigo es el siguiente.

tengo esta clase:

```
    <?php

    namespace controllers;


    class FilesController
    {

            public function saludo()
            {
                return "hola que tal";
            }

        };
```

y luego tengo el fichero index.php  con el siguiente código

```
use controllers\FilesController;

$nuevo = new FilesController();

echo $nuevo->saludo();
```

No se que esta mal sinceramente, otras veces lo he hecho y no ha habido ningún problema.

Versión PHP 7.2
en localhost 
Ubuntu

Ya he probado agregando el constructor a la clase pero tampoco funciona, siempre error 500.

Gracias

Comment: Me da la sensación que te falta incluir el archivo donde se encuentra la clase `FilesController`. Para que sepas exactamente la razón del error te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124722/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-error-reporting).

Comment: Gracias Marcos ; la primera linea del index apunta directamente el namespace de la clase y a la clase en si , de hecho el phpstorm me lo subraya cuando no esta.

Comment: Creo que el problema es ``use``, probaste lo mismo pero con ``include``??

Comment: Revisa el log de errores, ahí vas a encontrar el mensaje de error completo y sabrás a qué se debe.

Comment: Diría que el use es solo de controllers y qué te falta un include a la clase. Un saludo